# Ubuntu upgrade mouse problems

Tags: ubuntu

Since changing Ubuntu to the latest version where they unfortunately got rid of Unity, my mouse has been hypersensitive, and the settings in the new version don't give me an easy way to change the mouse sensitivity like it did in the previous version. How do I set up my mouse so that it turns off the touchpad when I am typing on this downgrade, or is there a way to switch back to Unity where I had the ability to easily fix this type of problem?

Answer (score 0):

Well I have the similar problem in Ubuntu 16.04. My muse is hypersensitive since first system start-up. I found the solution. Just open terminal and type "xset m 1/2 4". Mouse sensitivity will be decreased. You can also experiment with setting 6 or 8 instead of 4 as well as making it "default". All of them helped. But there is still another problem - Every time I start system - I should set it again... it's very annoying. 
Maybe you have some idea how to fix it?